# Need some hand-holding to render, display and save an image

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I've previously asked how I might be able to display my colour buffer and also save it to disk, and the answer I got was that I should;

> Render to a FBO and use glReadPixels() to slurp images out of that instead of the front buffer.

[How can I generate a screenshot when glReadPixels is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171174/how-can-i-generate-a-screenshot-when-glreadpixels-is-empty)

However, I've read a bit about framebuffers and am still totally confused, so I thought I would ask about how to do this on SO. My code does something like this:

```
    /* Callback handler for window re-paint event */
    void display()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);  //Clear the color buffer         
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);    //To operate on the model-view matrix

        // do some rendering

        glFlush(); // display
    }
```

when I want to save the image at any point, I run this:

```
    std::unique_ptr<RGBA2D> GrabScreen()
    {
        //we get the width/height of the screen into this array
        GLint screen[4];

        //get the width/height of the window
        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, screen);

        GLint width = screen[2];
        GLint height = screen[3];

        std::unique_ptr<RGBA2D> pixels(new RGBA2D(height, width * 4));

        glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels->data());
        return std::move(pixels);
    }
```

Note that `RGBA2D` is a 2D eigen vector object (not important). This all works fine, except that it only saves the image if it is being displayed. I want to be able to run my program on a unix machine without a display. I want to *render to an FBO*. How do I do this?

Comment: To be honest, I don't think the answer you were previously given was complete. You should really use Pixel Buffer Objects to read-back rendered image data from GL asynchronously. Otherwise, what winds up happening is you you unnecessarily stall the graphics pipeline so that `glReadPixels (...)` *immediately* returns a *completed* image. With PBOs you can tell GL you are interested in the pixel data, but rather than read it immediately you can periodically check to see if the data is available yet. When it is available, you can read it back without a stall.

Comment: I realize that if you are having trouble with FBOs, this extra complexity is not going to help anything. But this should be your ultimate goal. There is a reasonable overview of the whole process [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not hand-holding, but I can hopefully point you in the right direction.

You will use `glGenFramebuffers` and `glBindFramebuffer` to create and bind a Framebuffer Object (FBO).

Then you have a choice if you want to render to a texture or to a renderbuffer. For your purpose, either one will work. The renderbuffer is easier, IMHO. Use `glGenRenderbuffers`, `glBindRenderbuffer` and `glRenderbufferStorage` to set up your color renderbuffer.

Then you attach your color renderbuffer to the FBO, using `glFramebufferRenderbuffer`.

If you need a depth buffer, repeat the previous two steps to create and attach another renderbuffer used as the depth buffer for your FBO rendering.

Then do your rendering, and grab the frame with `glReadPixels`.

All these calls are documented in [the man pages at www.opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/). If you search for the keywords and some of the function names, you should also be able to find some full code samples.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had a small discussion on the Wayland devel maillist where I wanted to demonstrate how FBOs don't get updated when the X-Server managing the GPU is not holding the VT. Anyway, for demonstration purposes I hacked a quick and dirty program from various sources I had around, that renders to an FBO in a loop and writes the created picture out to a file. It's not optimized for performance, but does what you're interested in, so I drop the source code here (note that the `malloc` for the readout buffer misses a paired `free`, so there's a nongrowing memory leak in there)

```
// framebuffer continuous dump demonstrator
//
// build:
// c++  -o test_fbo test_fbo.cpp -lm -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lGLEW


#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

namespace render
{
    int width, height;
    float aspect;

    void init();
    void reshape(int width, int height);
    void display();

    int const fbo_width = 512;
    int const fbo_height = 512;

    GLuint fb, color, depth;

    void *dumpbuf;
    int dumpbuf_fd;
};

void idle();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );

    glutCreateWindow("FBO test");
    glutDisplayFunc(render::display);
    glutReshapeFunc(render::reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glewInit();

    render::init();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void CHECK_FRAMEBUFFER_STATUS()
{                                                         
    GLenum status;
    status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER); 
    switch(status) {
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
        break;

    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
    /* choose different formats */
        break;

    default:
        /* programming error; will fail on all hardware */
        throw "Framebuffer Error";
    }
}

namespace render
{
    float const light_dir[]={1,1,1,0};
    float const light_color[]={1,0.95,0.9,1};

    void init()
    {
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
        glGenTextures(1, &color);
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depth);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color);
        glTexImage2D(   GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                0, 
                GL_RGB8, 
                fbo_width, fbo_height,
                0, 
                GL_RGBA, 
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                NULL);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, color, 0);

        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, fbo_width, fbo_height);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth);

        GLint red_bits, green_bits, blue_bits, alpha_bits;

        glGetIntegerv(GL_RED_BITS,   &red_bits);
        glGetIntegerv(GL_GREEN_BITS, &green_bits);
        glGetIntegerv(GL_BLUE_BITS,  &blue_bits);
        glGetIntegerv(GL_ALPHA_BITS, &alpha_bits);

        fprintf(stderr, "FBO format R%dG%dB%dA%d\n",
            (int)red_bits,
            (int)green_bits,
            (int)blue_bits,
            (int)alpha_bits );

        CHECK_FRAMEBUFFER_STATUS();

        dumpbuf_fd = open("/tmp/fbodump.rgb", O_CREAT|O_SYNC|O_RDWR, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
        assert(-1 != dumpbuf_fd);
        dumpbuf = malloc(fbo_width*fbo_height*3);
        assert(dumpbuf);
    }

    void reshape(int width, int height)
    {
        render::width=width;
        render::height=height;
        aspect=float(width)/float(height);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    void prepare()
    {
        static float a=0, b=0, c=0;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

        glViewport(0,0,fbo_width, fbo_height);

        glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45, 1, 1, 10);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_dir);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_color);

        glTranslatef(0,0,-5);

        glRotatef(a, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(b, 0, 1, 0);
        glRotatef(c, 0, 0, 1);

        glutSolidTeapot(0.75);

        a=fmod(a+0.1, 360.);
        b=fmod(b+0.5, 360.);
        c=fmod(c+0.25, 360.);

        glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
        glReadPixels(0,0,fbo_width,fbo_height,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,dumpbuf);
        lseek(dumpbuf_fd, SEEK_SET, 0);
        write(dumpbuf_fd, dumpbuf, fbo_width*fbo_height*3);

    }

    void intermediary()
    {
    }

    void final()
    {
        static float a=0, b=0, c=0;

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

        glViewport(0,0, width, height);

        glClearColor(1.,1.,1.,0.);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45, aspect, 1, 10);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(0,0,-5);

        glRotatef(b, 0, 1, 0);

        b=fmod(b+0.5, 360.);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

        float cube[][5]=
        {
            {-1, -1, -1,  0,  0},
            { 1, -1, -1,  1,  0},
            { 1,  1, -1,  1,  1},
            {-1,  1, -1,  0,  1},

            {-1, -1,  1, -1,  0},
            { 1, -1,  1,  0,  0},
            { 1,  1,  1,  0,  1},
            {-1,  1,  1, -1,  1},
        };
        unsigned int faces[]=
        {
            0, 1, 2, 3,
            1, 5, 6, 2,
            5, 4, 7, 6,
            4, 0, 3, 7,
            3, 2, 6, 7,
            4, 5, 1, 0
        };

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 5*sizeof(float), &cube[0][0]);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 5*sizeof(float), &cube[0][3]);

        glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, faces);

        glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, faces);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    }

    void display()
    {
        prepare();
        intermediary();
        final();

        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your attached texture image appears to be missing an alpha channel (`GL_RGB8`) vs. the pixel transfer format (`GL_RGBA`). It is not terribly important since there is no actual pixel transfer, but it does leave me wondering if you intended the framebuffer to store alpha or not.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Probably a lot more of worms in there. I just had this thing open in a Vim and could copy'n'paste it (look at the Wayland Devel maillist for a recent discussion about Deep Color for which I hacked this from snippets out of various programs).